# In Go, what is the Superko rule, and is it used universally?

Tags: go

What is the Superko rule in Go?  Is it used in most scoring/online systems, or only in certain ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main Superko rule types, and, as long as the ruleset used isn’t Japanese, one of them should be in place.

Namely they are Positional and Situational.

**Positional superko** is used in the Chinese Rules, and prohibits the repetition of a position or board state, regardless of whose turn it is.

**Situational superko** is used in the AGA and BGA (American and British Go Association) rules, and prohibits the repetition of a position or board state, with the same player to play.
The variant **Natural situational superko** used by the BGA only forbids repetition by the player who created the position.

For more information on superko take a look at [Sensei’s Library](http://senseis.xmp.net/?Superko)